# Strange Behavior on Delete

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page with a table of rows (child objects),and each row has a delete button for removing the record.  When the user clicks "Delete" the row is removed from the list and the table is rerendered.  When the user clicks "Save" the rows are deleted from the database.  The user can also click "Cancel" and no records are deleted.

I am seeing some strange behavior after the second time the user clicks delete.  Though the row/record is appropriately removed from the list, one of the fields on the row (a lookup field, program__c) takes the value of the row that is deleted.

*Additional Thoughts per comments: After some help from the community it appears that the problem is "immediate = true" on my delete button.  Yet I need to rerender immediately, otherwise, I can't delete if a required field is not filled in.  Is there another way to bypass the rules on delete?*

These images shows what happens-

Original Table:

[image]

After first delete (of PAD-000156):

[image]

After second delete (of PAD-000157):

[image]

So of course the big problem is that comparing pictures after first delete with after second delete though PAD-000157 is deleted, the lookup field, program__c, of PAD-000158 takes on the value of PAD-000157 (in this example where the value should be 32-31: HOPE, the value of program becomes 32-00: F&I Counseling, which is the program of the record just deleted.

I'm going to post my whole page and controller because I'm really having trouble isolating where the issue is.  I've been working on this issue for the last week, so I'd really appreciate any advice or thoughts.  Thanks!

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Payroll_Authorization__c" sidebar="false" doctype="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" extensions="PayrollAuthorization_extn" applyBodyTag="true" lightningStylesheets="true">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>


 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
      .form-control {
          padding: 6px !important;
      }
      .btn-info {
        color: #fff!important;
        background-color: #5bc0de !important;
        border-color: #46b8da !important;
        background-image: none !important;
        padding: 8px 20px !important;
    }
     .table>thead>tr>th{


       vertical-align: top !important;
        text-align: left !important;
  }
  .table>tbody>tr>td{
        vertical-align: top !important;
        text-align: left !important;
  }
  .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
        padding: 4px !important;
    }
    .list-group-item {
        padding: 6px 15px !important;
    }
```

```
function calctotal(){
    //   alert ("caltotal" + {!PayrollDistributionList.size}); 
      var tempRowTotal=0;
      var percenttotal= 0;
for(var i=1; i<={!PayrollDistributionList.size};i++ ){

          tempRowTotal = ($('.wh'+i).val()!= null && $('.wh'+i).val() != '')?parseFloat($('.wh'+i).val()):0.0;
          percenttotal  += tempRowTotal;

        }
    return percenttotal;   
}

function calcRow(){
    //   alert ("calrow"); 

    var tempRowTotal=0;
     var percenttotal= 0;
       percenttotal= calctotal(); 
    for(var i=1; i<={!PayrollDistributionList.size};i++ ){  
      tempRowTotal = ($('.wh'+i).val()!= null && $('.wh'+i).val() != '')?parseFloat($('.wh'+i).val()):0.0;
      $('.wp' + i).text(((tempRowTotal * 100)/percenttotal).toFixed(2)+'%');
      $('.percenttotal').text(percenttotal.toFixed(2)+'%');     
      }
  }
    $(document).ready(function(){
          {
              calcRow();
          }

  });    

</script>
```

```
</script>
</head>
```

```
    <div align="center" draggable="false" style="font-size:13px; margin-bottom:4px"  >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!SavePA}" styleclass="btn btn-info" style="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" styleclass="btn btn-info" immediate="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="container-flud" style="font-size: 11.5px;">
        <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: -15px;">
            <ul class="list-group">      
                <li class="list-group-item row" style="background-color: #702342;color: #fff;padding: 6px 10px;">
                    <h4 style="margin: 2px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bolder;">Payroll Authorization</h4>
                </li>
            </ul>

  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <ul class="list-group">      
        <li class="list-group-item row" style="background-color: #702342;color: #fff;padding: 6px 10px;">
            <h4 style="margin: 2px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bolder;">Payroll Distributions</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Payroll Distribution" id="er" >   
            <table class="table table-bordered" >

            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>    
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Program
                </th>
                <th>
                    Percentage worked
                </th>
                <th>
                    Percentage total
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:variable var="SelectedRowId" value="{!0}"/>
                <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="index"/>  
            <apex:repeat value="{!PayrollDistributionList}" var="pd">
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" immediate="true" reRender="er" >
                            <apex:param name="RowID" value="{!pd.ID}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!pd.name}
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputfield value="{!pd.Program__c}"   style="Width: 50%"/></td>
                    <td ><apex:inputfield value="{!pd.Program_Percent__c}" styleClass="wh{!index}" onkeyup="calcRow()"/> </td>
                    <td Class="wp{!index}">
                        0%
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <apex:variable value="{!index+1}" var="index"/>

            </apex:repeat>
        </tbody>
    <tfoot> <tr>
        <th/>
        <th/>
        <th/>
            <th class="percenttotal">
                0.0%
            </th>
            <th>
                100.00%
            </th>
          </tr></tfoot>
      </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>
    </div>

        <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Program" immediate="true" reRender="er, scriptPanel"/>

    </apex:form>

</body>
```

Controller Extension:

```
public with sharing class PayrollAuthorization_extn {

public list <PA_Distribution__c> PayrollDistributionList {get; set;}
public Payroll_Authorization__c PA;
public String rowID {get;set;}
public List<PA_Distribution__c> delProgramList {get; set;} 


public PayrollAuthorization_extn(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

PA = (Payroll_Authorization__c)controller.getRecord();
PayrollDistributionList = [Select Id, Name, Program__c, Program_Percent__c, Program_as_Number__c
        From PA_Distribution__c 
        Where Payroll_Authorization__r.id =: controller.getId()
        ];  
delProgramList = new List<PA_Distribution__c>();            
}

public void addRow(){
    PayrollDistributionList.add(new PA_Distribution__c( Payroll_Authorization__c = PA.id));
}

public PageReference SavePA (){
   // upsert PA; 
    System.debug ('Upsert:' + PayrollDistributionList);
    upsert PayrollDistributionList;
    System.debug ('Delete:' + delProgramList);
    delete delProgramList;

    return (new ApexPages.StandardController(PA)).view();
}

public void deleteRow(){

    PA_Distribution__c del;
    rowID =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RowID');

    For (Integer i=0; i<PayrollDistributionList.size(); i++){
        System.debug ('Current list size is' +  PayrollDistributionList.size() + ' Iteration:' + i);
        del= PayrollDistributionList[i];
        If (del.Id == rowID) {

            System.debug('Delete index: ' + i +  PayrollDistributionList[i]);
            System.debug(PayrollDistributionList);
            PayrollDistributionList.remove(i);
            System.debug('List remaining is ' + PayrollDistributionList );

           If(del.Id <> null) delProgramList.add(del);
            System.debug ('Delete these: ' + delProgramList);


            i = PayrollDistributionList.size();
        }

    }
   }


}
```

Comment: great Question! minor change to improve the code: replace `i = PayrollDistributionList.size();` with `break;`

Comment: did you also test, if the percentage field would be replaced too? rigth now we can't see it, cause they are both 20. I have a guess, that it might be related to the way you are using instant=true and the rerendering. Did you check, if the lookup_id (that is stored hidden in the DOM) did also change? It feels a bit like the rerendering does not replace the field cause some element id's didn't change. It's a weird thought, but it's also a weird bug ;)

Comment: Your code appears to be confusing the Visualforce runtime, such that certain values are getting attributed to the wrong input fields. I suspect either it's undefined behavior because of the apex:variable in the loop, or because of immediate="true", or perhaps even just because of how you're rendering. Long story short, I think you're in got a total rewrite if you can't sort out the problem.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox.  It appears that "Immediate = true" is indeed the problem.  I need the immediate true so a user can delete a row without having to pass validation/required field rules.  Any thoughts on a work around?

Comment: @Basti thanks for your reply.  The percentage field is not replaced.  When I make a formula field with lookup_id even that seems correct.  Its just that the lookup field that is displayed is showing wrong because of the immediate rerendering.  Any other thoughts/workarounds?

Comment: @cmayer10 that's not what I ment. Please check the DOM (Page Source) before and after that change. Next to the lookup field is a hidden field, that contains the id of the lookup. Check if the name that is displayed also belongs to the hidden id. (might be the wrong direction though)